# PyCharm: Embed code of imported functions automatically

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I'm more or less the only one in my office who codes little scripts for the analysis of data in Python. Hence I have a small library of helper functions which I reuse every now and than in different scripts; this library is placed centrally in the Anaconda librarys on my machine.

Sometimes though, I want to "deploy" the scripts as standalone version, so they could be run on a plain python distribution, i.e. without first having to "install" my library files.

Is there any way in PyCharm to automatically replace **certain** import statements by the code of the imported functions? I know this can be a complex task to determine whether the function-code to be embedded further relies on different functions again which also need to be imported (but somehow PyInstaller also gets these dependencies). But mainly I'm talking about functions which do not have any further dependencies or only within the same module...

***To give an example:***

Maybe my library looks like this:

```
def readfile(filepath): 
   return ....

def readfileAsList(filepath):
   return readfile(filepath).splitlines()

def writefile(contents, filepath, writemode='w'):
   with open(filepath, writemode): 
     ...
```

And my script for some analysis looks like this:

```
import re
from myLib import readfileAsList
# ANALYSIS CODE GOES HERE ...
```

Now I want PyCharm to automatically transform the script-code and embed `readfileAsList` as well as `readfile` (because of the dependencies).

So the code would look like:

```
import re
def readfile(filepath): 
   return ....

def readfileAsList(filepath):
   return readfile(filepath).splitlines()

# ANALYSIS CODE GOES HERE ...
```

Thanks in advance!